# Log4net переключение между базами

Tags: c#, log4net

Есть служба windows, которая занимается обновлением информации в разных БД , которые могут находится на разных серверах. В каждой из этих БД есть таблица, куда должны писаться логи.

Логи должны писаться для каждой отдельной базы в таблицу логов именно этой базы. Выходит, что мне нужно каким-то образом в зависимости от того с какой базой работает служба в данный момент - на эту базу переключать и `log4net`.

Поддерживается ли такая возможность в `log4net`, и как приблизительно это можно реализовать ?

Comment: Настройте 2 логгера и используйте нужный, в зависимости от базы.

Comment: @tym32167 хорошая идея, а как это делается ? Просто с трудом представляю, как я ему подсуну другой коннекшн стринг

Comment: 1. Определяете 2 аппендера в конфигах (с разными настройками для БД) 2. Определяете 2 логгера с разными именами и аппендерами там же в кофиге. 3) В коде при получении логгера, получаете нужный логгер (по имени) в зависимости от вашей БД (LogManager.GetLogger(name))

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо, это помогло. Если будет желание, сделайте это ответом

Comment: Оформил ответом. Рад, что помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как настроить 2 логгера в log4net

1. Определяете 2 аппендера в конфигах (с разными настройками для БД)
2. Определяете 2 логгера с разными именами и соответствующими аппендерами там же в кофиге
3. В коде при получении логгера, получаете нужный логгер (по имени) в зависимости от вашей БД (LogManager.GetLogger(name))